# How to modify bash line obtained by bpf_probe_read_user function from (void*)PT_REGS_RC(ctx)?

Tags: ebpf

I want to modify bash readline function's return string (command line text) value in a uretprobe ebpf function.

I have written a uretprobe type ebpf code that works on the bash "readline" function. I can read the command line text entered with the "bpf_probe_read_user" helper function. When I try to replace it with a shorter string using "bpf_probe_write_user", there is no problem, but in a longer expression it gives a "realloc error". I'm guessing it is due to the insufficient size of the static string expression currently maintained by Bash and not being able to reallocation.

How can I push a longer expression (e.g. a like "echo unauthorized command!") into it and allow bash to execute this command?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are at the limits of what it possible. You can copy data into a userspace program but if you write a longer string than what bash has allocated, you are essentially performing a heap overflow attack.

You can perhaps overwrite the string pointer to change it to another memory location, but you have no way of knowing what that location is used for. You are now in the territory of binary exploration and its counter measures like [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) which aims to make doing what you are doing extra difficult.

I would recommend you look into other ways to achieve granular security such as [LSM programs](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/prog_lsm.html).